# JS error message textContent set as null

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to JS and the world of web development, so apologise in advance if my question is a bit tedious.

I wrote this code:

```
var breakfast = new Object();
breakfast.food = "croissant";
breakfast.extra = ["mushroom", "cheese"];
breakfast.eat = function(){return this.food + " with " +  this.extra[0];}
var elBreakfast = document.getElementById("breakf");
elBreakfast.textContent = breakfast.eat();
```

I get an error message from the browser:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null"...
```

What have I done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `ID` right ? Is it `breakf` ?

Comment: It means that `elBreakfast` is null. `getElementById` returns `null` if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you put your html code.

Answer (score 7):

The only important code here is `document.getElementById("breakf");`. It seems like your browser is unable to query for the element with an ID of `breakf` within your HTML markup.

So you need to check your HTML code live in your browser. Check if there is any HTML node with `id=breakf`. If not, you correctly should receive that error.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's sorted. It was a silly mistake. I put my script link before the id tag in the html. So the  "breakf" didn't exist at the time the script was run. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CamC I think it would be useful if you write your comment as an answear. There are a lot of other silly people around the world. (Which includes me...)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add script  reference end of body tag in html page so that it will load breakf element and then applies the breakfast.eat();